# Flutter SDK location after install with ubuntu snap

Tags: android-studio, flutter, ubuntu

I'm trying to get Flutter + Android Studio set up as per the guidelines in https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux

I installed flutter using ubuntu "snap" by running:

```
$ sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

When setting up a Flutter project in android studio now, it's asking me to enter a Flutter SDK path. I can't find a path that satisfies the flutter SDK path requirement. The one that I tried so far is `/snap/flutter/current` but that didn't seem to work. Any ideas on where the SDK is located before I go ahead and redownload it to some local directory in /home/...?

Comment: try installing it manually and without using snap. That's how I did it and was able to place it in any directory I want.

Comment: `/snap/bin/flutter` have you look at this path @de1337ed

Comment: Yes, but it seems like that's just an executable, not the path that Android Studio is looking for, unfortunately.

Answer (score 25):

I installed the same way, and I found the flutter SDK in my home path under snap flutter common flutter

```
/home/foobaruser/snap/flutter/common/flutter
```

also, you can check your path with

```
flutter doctor -v
```

Comment: Yes exactly it was inside the `home` directory. When perform `which flutter` it gave `/snap/bin/flutter` don't know why. Anyway thank you for your help :D

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer! Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 2):

After installing flutter using:

```sh
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

In the same shell, you have to execute [(check the note)](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#get-sdk):

```sh
flutter sdk-path
```

It will generate all SDK files in:

```sh
/home/$USER/snap/flutter/common/flutter
```